# How to lunch an applications on linux using python script?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I have to lunch multiple similar application regularly on Linux machine so I want to write a script to open them without fail.

Could you please help me here to write a script to open multiple applications at a time.

Example: Firefox and Libre office cal

Can you please suggest the script which can able to open these above applications(Firefox and Libre office cal) so that I can build customized script to open multiple applications.

Script:

```
import os
import browser
from threading import Thread

def app1(my_app_name):

  os.system(my_app_name)


def main():
 t1 = Thread(target=app1, args=(('firefox',)) )
 #t2 = Thread(target=app1 , args=(('libreoffice',)) )
 t1.start()
 #t2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Comment: you can use threading and (os) moduole

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe it useful :

```
import os
from threading import Thread

def app1(my_app_name):

  os.system(my_app_name)


def main():
 t1 = Thread(target=app1, args=(('firefox',)) )
 t2 = Thread(target=app1 , args=(('libreoffice',)) )
 t1.start()
 t2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

i used (os) for excute linux command shell ( also you can use it for windows)
 and Thread for run programs at parallel

Comment: Can you take an example as app1=Firefox & app2= libre office cal and write the script?

Comment: i now check that

Comment: it's worked for me just use firefox instead of 'ls' or any program or linux command

Comment: what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: @MaheshAknur  is there any problem ? if no please accept and put mark in my solution

Comment: I'm getting beloow error when I try to run a script.{'firefox': [None, <webbrowser.Mozilla object at 0x7f3bf5ccdb50>], 'gvfs-open': [None, <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x7f3bf5cac850>], 'gnome-open': [None, <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x7f3bf5cac8d0>], 'xdg-open': [None, <webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x7f3bf5cac950>], 'google-chrome': [None, <webbrowser.Chrome object at 0x7f3bf5ccdbd0>]}

Comment: i tested code and it worked for me problem is in your firefox you can just test another programs and you will see it's work this error is not from my code

Comment: type firefox in terminal is there any issue ? or it opened without problem ?

Comment: @MaheshAknur do you check another programs ? do you have still problem ?

Comment: It's working from terminal using firefox command but through script it's not working.

Comment: in my pc it work very well ! you can check another programs

Comment: i just used a linux commands in this code so any problem must with your firefox

Comment: Yes, I will check it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Appication open.py", line 4, in <module>
    import browser
ImportError: No module named browser

Now I'm getting this error

Comment: it's say you your python hasn't browser module

Comment: please copy your code and paste in your question

Comment: import os
import browser
from threading import Thread

def app1(my_app_name):

  os.system(my_app_name)


def main():
 t1 = Thread(target=app1, args=(('firefox',)) )
 #t2 = Thread(target=app1 , args=(('libreoffice',)) )
 t1.start()
 #t2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()

Comment: use right format pate this to your question part i can't understanding your code .

Comment: what is import browser ? python has not this module remove it

Comment: Great thanks....
It's working now....:)

Comment: you can use webbrowser